# chmod: changing permissions of Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, centos, permissions

I have an error everytime i do something to 3 folder i have an error

`chmod: changing permissions of ‘’: Operation not permitted`

1. This error only happen to 3 folder 
   [image]
2. it happen after after i press this command

`chattr +a Koordinator*`

I think this is the affect after i use that command, now i can't do anything to these 3 folder even as root, is there any way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `chattr +a` on a directory makes it so that files and subdirectories can be created inside but the directory itself can't be deleted, moved, or have its permissions changed. Files and subdirectories inside aren't affected and can still be modified but they can't be moved or deleted.

To be able to change the permissions or anything else with those directories, use the following command to remove the attribute:

```
chattr -a Koordinator*
```

I recommend reading the man page on `chattr` and researching what the different options do.

Comment: it works, thanks